# JdbcTemplate query retuns null set - Spring boot, MySQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am trying to get all rows in a table using `JdbcTemplate.query` in a Spring boot application. I use a MySQL database for this. I wrote a test class to insert data and query the inserted data by it's primary key. It works fine. But the test case I wrote to get all the data in table returns a null result set even if there are some data in the table. I can query the table using MySQL console and it shows data in the table, same time. What have I done wrong? Please help.

> Code in the user repository class,

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM db_users", new UserRowMapper());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM db_users WHERE username=?", new Object[]{username},
                new UserRowMapper());
    }

    public User addNewUser(final User user) {
        final String query = "INSERT INTO db_users(username,email,first_name,Last_name,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getEmail());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getFirstName());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getLastName());
                preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPassword());

                return preparedStatement;
            }
        });

        return user;
    }
}
```

> UserRowMapper class

```
class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User(resultSet.getString("username"), resultSet.getString("email"),
                    resultSet.getString("first_name"), resultSet.getString("last_name"), resultSet.getString("password"));

            return user;
        }
    }
```

> Code in the test case;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void createUserTest() {
        User user = new User("testuser", "test@email.com", "Firstname", "Lastname", "password");
        User savedUser = userRepository.addNewUser(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void findUserByUsernameTest() {
        User user = userRepository.getUserByUsername("testuser");
        assertNotNull(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllUsersTest() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.getAllUsers();
        assertNotNull(users);
        assertTrue(!users.isEmpty());
    }
```

> What I get is,

```
getAllUsersTest(com.sol16.core.UserTests.UserRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.026 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:55)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:31)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue(TestCase.java:201)
    at com.sol16.core.UserTests.UserRepositoryTest.getAllUsersTest(UserRepositoryTest.java:52)
```

Comment: According to your stack trace, the second assertion fails. So the list of users is empty.

Comment: My problem is, there are data in the table. But the list says that it is empty. What is the reason for this list to be empty one?

Comment: That there isn't any data... Or at least not visible for the application (did you commit the other transaction, are you looking at the correct database?).

Comment: I assume that you're not using the real database, but a in-memory-database instead. Can you check that?

Comment: I checked it again, there are data in the MySQL database. I can ensure that It is the correct database. This issue only occurs in the test case, whenever I try to do `maven clean package`. The `getAllUsers()` function is working correctly and returns the users list when I'm running the spring boot application.

Comment: why do You mix Hibernate with low-lewel JDBC, especially with UPDATES ? Seems wrong idea ...

Comment: you shouldn't mix up data between tests .there are some recommendations according to test dao layer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-dao-testing

Comment: What is the code for "UserRowMapper" ?? i am betting that you have the implemented incorrectly.

Comment: @Jeryl I have updated the question adding that part. :)

Comment: i want to recommend you using an in-memory database for test cases. also check the database directly in your test case inject @Autowire DataSource  , and create a JDBCTemplate in your test case and query perhaps to see why its empty.

Comment: Did you check if `userRepository` injected successfully?